# Trying to show data from localstorage to ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to show data from my `localstorage` to my `ion-input` here is my form (edituser.html)

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item>        
                <ion-label> <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="userData.fullname" value="{{userDetails.fullname}}" type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

         <ion-item>        
                <ion-label> <ion-icon name="md-phone-portrait"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                <ion-input  [(ngModel)]="userData.phone" value="{{userDetails.phone}}"  type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>        
                <ion-label> <ion-icon name="md-mail"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                <ion-input  [(ngModel)]="userData.Email" value="{{userDetails.Email}}"  type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>        
                <ion-label> <ion-icon name="md-megaphone"></ion-icon></ion-label>
                <ion-input  [(ngModel)]="userData.Deskripsi" value="{{userDetails.Deskripsi}}"  type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

here is how i store my `localstorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
```

and `this.responseData`

```
{"userData": {"user_id":"USER001","username":"boby","password":"c83e4046a7c5d3c4bf4c292e1e6ec681","fullname":"Boby Kurniawan","phone":"0896889....","profilpic":null,"status":null,"flag":1,"tipe":"TP001","Deskripsi":"Lorem Ipsum is ........Ipsum","Email":"asdddd@gmail.com"}}
```

here is my full `edituser.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

 @IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-edituser',
  templateUrl: 'edituser.html',
})
export class EdituserPage {
userDetails : any;
responseData: any;
userData = {"username": "","password": "", "fullName": "","Email": "", "Deskripsi" : "", "Phone":""};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
        this.userDetails = data.userData;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.userDetails);
  }

}
```

So, my problem is, In edituser.html only show two field (fullname & phone) only. How can i fix it  ?

here is the screenshot

[image]

Update, (using native storage module.)

Because i want to store the result from my API so i add it in my login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController,LoadingController,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  responseData : any;
  userData = {"username": "","password": "", "fullName": "","Email": "", "Deskripsi" : "", "Phone":""};

  constructor(
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public authService:AuthService, 
              public loadingCtrl:LoadingController, 
              public alrt : AlertController,
              public storage: Storage ) {
              storage.clear();
  }

presentAlert(msg) {
  let alert = this.alrt.create({
    title: msg,
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}

  login(){

    this.authService.postData(this.userData,'Login').then((result) => {
    this.responseData = result;
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Proses Login'
      });
      loading.present();
    if(this.responseData.userData){
       setTimeout(() => {
            storage.set('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
                loading.dismiss();
                  this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage, {}, {animate: true});
          }, 5000);
     }else{ 
        loading.dismiss();
        this.presentAlert("Failed to Login"); }
    }, (err) => {
        this.presentAlert("Error !!!");
    });

  }
}
```

But i get this error

> ERROR ReferenceError: storage is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend **not to use** browser `localstorage` API. Since you are developing native app use [**native storage module**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). Since you need to install the `SQLite` plugin you'll have very reliable storage mechanism under any circumstance.

> Storage is an easy way to store key/value pairs and JSON objects.
>   Storage uses a variety of storage engines underneath, picking the best
>   one available depending on the platform.

*From the Doc:*

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ...

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Comment: sorry, can you tell me how is not finisihed sentence. I already try it and get this             `Cannot find name 'storage'. Did you mean 'Storage'?`

Comment: Did you `import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';` this?

Comment: You need to use `this.storage`

Comment: You need to set that in `app.module.ts`.All details are there in the doc.